# Is there a way to explicitly set a program's exact DPI scaling value?

Tags: windows-10, scaling, high-dpi

I have a program that is fussy when it comes to DPI scaling, and the high DPI settings in the Compatibility Properties are not working for this particular program, no matter the combination of settings I use.

Essentially, the program is designed to work at 1440p at *exactly* 150% scaling. It works just fine if I have my monitor set at 150%. However, I need my monitor to be at 100% scaling for ordinary use, or else everything looks really big.

Is there any way to force the program to *think* that the monitor is set at 150% instead?

Answer (score 0):

No. The values for 1440p and 150% scaling are either explicitly mentioned by the programmer or they are read from an encrypted settings file, to which you don't have access to, because you don't know where it is or you don't know how to modify it.

My advice to you is to leave an e-mail to the program creators and state your problem. They may be able to help you more efficiently.